# Strange SVD Bound with Frobenius Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, svd, singular-values

For any matrix $A$, show that
$$
\sigma_k \le ||A||_F/\sqrt{k}
$$
where $\sigma_k$ is the $k$-th singular value of $A$.

For $k=1$ I would say it's trivial, but for $k>1$?

Also tried this looking the link
$$
\sigma_k=||Av_k||_2\le ||A||_F||v_k||_2 = ||A||_F
$$
since $v_k$ is othonormal vector.

Already read other questions [SVD Bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988695/frobenius-norm-inequality-with-svd) but can't find how to introduce that $k$ in the bound. Some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to note that 
$$
\|A\|_F^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_k^2 = k \sigma_k.
$$